# How should long queries relevant to a question be handled?

Tags: discussion

Where a question concerns query performance, how should the query be included in the question if it is very long (tens or even hundred of lines)?

On SO, code posted in a question should be whittled down to just the relevant lines. However, with an SQL query, subdividing it will change the behaviour and performance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend using [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) in this situation. It would also be helpful to attempt to use a [SQL formatter](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm) for a more compact formatting.